# Getting a Rectangle box with arrow on hover the link in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a rectangle box with an arrow on hover the links.

```
             <a href="//">NAME</a>
```

on hover this i am trying to get a rectangle box with an arrow .
For example
 like what we have in Facebook on hover of the Username we will be getting a rectangle box with contents inside it.

How to apply Css for this one  ?

[image]

Comment: could you please provide a screenshot to clearify what you would like to get?

Comment: @oezi Just like what we have in Facebook on hover of the Username we will be getting a rectangle box with contents inside it.

Comment: i've heard of facebook, but i'm not registered there (and i don't ever want to) - a screenshot would be nice, but after reading again, it soulds like you're just looking for a way to make beautiful tooltips. if so, take a look at this: http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/ or simply ask google for "beautiful tooltip"

Comment: Oezi is right, this is a tooltip. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your very vague question, I think you're after [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/DNypD/):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="Hover me!">Hover Me</a>
```

CSS:

```
a
{
    display: inline block;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;    
    background-color: transparent; /*default value, used here to illustrate*/

}

a:hover
{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

---

After your edit, we finally understand!

My suggestion is to go to [this very website](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) and acquaint yourself with their great tooltips. It's very versatile and very easy to implement, just include jQuery and their plugins, then setup the HTML.

It's easy :)

Comment: No i am trying to get a rectangle box positioned right above the name  as we have in facebook

Comment: Please provide a screenshot, your question is vague to the point of "what are you asking?"

Answer (score 1):

You can use css and jquery to achieve what you need. I made a fast example about this
http://jsbin.com/amaga4

I use three classes on for the link, `mylink` one for the popup div named `mypopup` and one for the text in the popup called `mytext`. The `mypopup` div has `display:none` in css to hide it.

The you can use jquery and events `mouseover` and `mouseleave` for the `.mylink a` and make visible the div `mypopup` using `show()` and hide it using `hide()`

**The CSS**

```
.mylink {width:300px; text-align:right;}
.mylink a {color:#0CF; font-size:20px; text-decoration:none;}
.mypopup {background:url(shape.png) no-repeat; width:300px; height:146px; color:#0CF; display:none;}
.mytext {position:relative; top:40px; left:20px;}
```

**The XHTML**

```
<div class="mylink"><a href="#">Here is my link</a></div>
<div class="mypopup"><div class="mytext">The text here</div></div>
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
    $(".mylink a").mouseover(function() { 
        $(".mypopup").show();
    });
    $(".mylink a").mouseleave(function() { 
        $(".mypopup").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i'm right, so i'm posting this as an answer: what you're looking for is a tooltip, and there are different solutions (with and without javascript) out there. my personal favourite is [prototip 2](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/).

to get exactly what facebook does, [this](http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/02/jquery-ajax-tooltip.html) will help you (based on [coda popup bubbles](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/)).

**EDIT:** if you alredy have a tooltip and just wan't to use css similar to the one of facebook, try to use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843/) (for firefox, in IE just press F12 and use the developer tools... chrome has something like this too, ask google) to inspect the html and the applied css-rules for that.

Comment: The Chrome version is activated by hitting `ctrl+shift+j`. :)